# Calling dictionaries from other functions and modules

Tags: python

Sorry for asking a newbie question, but I'm learning about functions, modules, and dictionaries, and having trouble combining the three concepts. Basically my question is, is there a way to create a dictionary in another module's function and use it as if it were in the current module's function?

My failed attempt at doing this is in my text RPG:

For the main.py:

```
import monsters # At top of program

monsters.monster_list # In the middle of the program

# Command loop during combat
def combat_loop():
    in_town = False
    monster_appear = True
    combat_active = True

    while monster_appear == True:
        # Pull a random monster from the appropriate level pool.
        monsters.monster_list(hero)
        print(f"A {monster['name']} appears!")
        print(f"You have {hero['current_health']} / {hero['max_health']} health remaining.")
        monster_appear = False
```

The monsters.py module is over 700 lines but I'll try to post all the relevant code:

```
def monster_list(hero):
# Monster List 
# Seed stats
    monster = {
        'name': "None",
        'health': 0,
        # Monster strength is used in figuring out how much damage will be done to you.
        'strength' : 0,
        # Monster agility is used in figuring out how much damage will be reduced for the enemy.
        'agility' : 0,
        'gold': 0,
        'exp':  0,
    }

    # Slime stats
    slime = {
        'name': "Slime",
        'health': 3,
        'strength' : 5,
        'agility' : 3,
        'gold': 1,
        'exp': 1
        # Slime has a 1/64 chance to Dodge
    }

    # Monster sets per level (edited for length). 
    monsters = ['slime', etc]

    # The following makes a list slice out of monsters from position 0
    # up to but not including 2 and so on.
    tier1_monsters = monsters[0:2]

    if hero['tier'] == 1:
        current_monster = random.choice(tier1_monsters)
        #Omitted the rest for length

        # Monster stats list - attached base slime stats to the current monster in combat
    if current_monster == 'slime':
        monster['name'] = slime['name']
        monster['health'] = slime['health']
        monster['strength'] = slime['strength']
        monster['agility'] = slime['agility']
        monster['gold'] = slime['gold']
        monster['exp'] = slime['exp']
       # Omitted for length
    return monster
```

This code crashes when the program tries to load the combat loop for the first time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_rpg_modules.py", line 781, in <module>
    combat_loop()
  File "my_rpg_modules.py", line 717, in combat_loop
    print(f"A {monster['name']} appears!")
NameError: name 'monster' is not defined
```

Again, I'm only just learning about these concepts so I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do is possible. The code worked before I added functions and modules. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Also, this code works if I paste the seed monster list into the main.py, but it says "A None appears!". The main program can't seem to pull the dictionary from the other module's function.

Comment: Everything I see are `monsters`, I don't see any variable called `monster`, you are calling a variable that you didn't define, double check it.

Comment: You have not written any code to "Pull a random monster", which (according to your comment) is what `monster` should be (once you bother to assign to it).

Comment: @TYZ it's in the local scope of `monsters.monster_list()`

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you haven't already. In the future, please provide a [mre], i.e. less code and complete code (`etc` is not defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to capture the return value of `monsters.monster_list`:

```
monster = monsters.monster_list(hero)
print(f"A {monster['name']} appears!")
```

It seems like you're confused because you originally had `monster` as a global that was modified every loop (which is very bad design - a newbie mistake), and you didn't fully switch to returning it. On that same note, `monster['name'] = slime['name']` is part of the same bad design. Instead, have `monsters.monster_list` simply return the `current_monster`:

```
if hero['tier'] == 1:
    return random.choice(tier1_monsters)
```

Comment: Thanks wjandrea, that seems to work. I removed monsters.monster_list(hero) from the combat loop and added monster = monsters.monster_list(hero), no more error.

Also, I definitely do need to work on shortening my code, it's a mess trying to find anything right now. Practice, practice, practice!

Comment: @Freyjas Welcome! I added a bit about what I think happened.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a variable in your monsters module named monster. `import monster` gives you the ability to access the library, but it does not typically bring all those functions and variables into the local namespace. To access such variable, you'll need to reference it as:

```
monsters.monster[name]
```

Alternatively, you can bring it into the local namespace with

```
from monsters import monster
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, everyone. I think the problem I'm having is that monster is a dictionary set, not a variable.  This worked ok when the monster dictionary was in the main program with no function, but now that it's in a function and in another module, "{monster['name']}" is not recognized.